# Loading images using Firebase Storage UI - Will image invalidate automatically when changed?

Tags: android, firebase-storage, firebaseui

I'm using Glide with Firebase Storage UI to load images directly using `StorageReference`. Will Glide invalidate the image automatically when the sourced image is changed with same file name?

```
Glide.with(context)
          .load(storageRef)
          .into(imageView);
```

I have tried but it's not invalidating.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the image via url and the image is deleted and glide already loaded the image, it will stay showing until your reload it. Then it won't show anymore because the new image will have a different url.
However, if you are loadin it directly from the storage reference, then it should work fine because you wouldn't be generating a new url.

Comment: What will happen if the image is just replaced?

Comment: Replacing in Firebase storage is basically deleting and uploading under the same name, you will delete the old image and upload the new image, however the new image url will not be the same as the old image so it won't work.

Comment: Update the post with some code to show some examples how do you use glide in this specific scenario.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. I'm using Firebase Storage UI. So it will load directly from storage reference instead of getting download URL.

Comment: That actually could work. Give it a try? and let me know if it works.

Comment: Okay... I will try and revert.